# Помогите понять в чем ошибка

Tags: c++

Вот код, по идее должен выводить элементы которых нет в массиве А, но он дорабатывает только до минимального и максимального элемента.

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream> 
#include <locale> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    const int n = 5;
    int a[n], Xmax = -100000, Xmin = 100000, b[n], i, j, resIndex, findElement;
    cout « "Введите элементы массива: " « endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin » a[i];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] > Xmax)
            Xmax = a[i];
        if(a[i] < Xmin)
            Xmin = a[i];
    }
    cout « "Максимальное число: " « Xmax « endl;
    cout « "Минимальное число: " « Xmin « endl;
    {
        int resIndex = -1;
        int findElement = 0;
        for(i = 0, j = 0; i = Xmin, i < Xmax; i++)
        {
            if(a[i] == findElement)
            {
                resIndex = true;
                b[j] = i;
                for(j = 0, j < n; i++;)
                    cout « b[j] « " " « endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Отладчик в руки и вперед!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что цикл

```
for(i = 0, j = 0; i = Xmin, i < Xmax; i++)
```

на каждой итерации присваивает `i` значение `Xmin`, потом проверяет, меньше ли оно `Xmax`, а так как оно меньше, цикл вечен... Был бы вечен, если бы не `break` в условии

```
if (a[i] == findElement)
```

так что выход из цикла осуществляется только при `a[Xmin]==findElement`.

Answer (score 4):

Цикл странный у вас, условие выхода в частности:

```
for(i = 0, j = 0; i = Xmin, i < Xmax; i++)
```

`findElement` у вас всегда равен `0`, вы его инициализируете и нигде не изменяете

Второй цикл ещё более странный

```
for(j = 0, j < n; i++;)
```

Счетчик инициализируете `j`, условие по `j`, увеличиваете `i`...

Разберитесь, что вы хотели сделать алгоритмически.

Comment: я просто пока учусь, и не смог придумать алгоритм для нахождения элементов не входящих в массив на интервале от минимума до максимума

Comment: Прежде чем писать код, всегда должен быть готов алгоритм. На бумажке или в голове.